# How to use MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway to take dynamic uri?

Tags: spring-integration

How to use `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway` to take dynamic `uri`. I am not sure how to use `uri`, and `uriExpression` when comes to java way of configuration.

Kindly help.

Comment: ??? `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` doesn't have `uri-expression`. It is a property of `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`...

Comment: Yeah I was looking at wrong place. I have to evaluate the expression outside and pass plain URI string to the WS gateway.

Comment: I was looking to do something like 

<ws:outbound-gateway request-channel="inputJms"
        uri="jms:{destination}?deliveryMode={deliveryMode}&amp;priority={priority}"
        message-sender="jmsMessageSender">
    <ws:uri-variable name="destination" expression="headers.jmsQueue"/>
    <ws:uri-variable name="deliveryMode" expression="headers.deliveryMode"/>
    <ws:uri-variable name="priority" expression="headers.jms_priority"/>
</ws:outbound-gateway>

Comment: OK. That's more cleaner. I'll answer to tomorrow.

Comment: Any idea how to configure dynamic uri, username, password.?

Comment: ??? Sorry, what is `username, password` in context of `ws:outbound-gateway` ?

Comment: soap header parameters inside soap:envelope

Comment: You can do that only injecting custom `SoapHeaderMapper` which overrides `populateUserDefinedHeader` and does `SoapHeader.addHeaderElement` and so on.